# How to get multiple data from different relational table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 relational tables : users, posts, and reposts.

In **reposts table**, I have fields: **user_id** (the user who reposted the post) and, **post_id**.

In **posts table**, I have fields: **id**, **posts**, and **user_id**.

In **users table**, I have field: **id** and **first_name**.

Here are what the data I wanted to get:

1. The post
2. The original user who posted
3. The reporter or the user who reposted the post.

So far i only have this query:

```
SELECT
p.post,
u.first_name as 'Retweeter'
FROM reposts r 
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.id = r.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.id = r.post_id
```

In that code I can get the post and the user who reposted the post. But how can I get the original user or the details of the original user who posted the post, using the post_id field from the reposts table?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You join in a strange order. Start with posts, then left join users, etc.

Comment: Join users once again, but this time on relation between post and user.

Comment: Does the repost may be reposted? Does you need original poster, not last reposter, in this case?

Comment: Oh my, I totally forgot about the function where the repost can be reposted, but I'm planning to have another field in my posts table repost_id in where I can store the repost.id to distinguish if the post is repost or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need one more join on `users` table for getting original poster name

```
SELECT
  ou.first_name originalPoster,
  p.post,
  u.first_name as 'Retweeter'
FROM reposts r 
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.id = r.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.id = r.post_id 
LEFT JOIN users ou
    on p.user_id = ou.id
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to join `users` twice, once against `posts` and once against `reposts`. If you want to include posts that haven't been reposted, you should start the `FROM` clause with `posts` and then do the left joins.

```
SELECT p.post,
       up.first_name,
       urp.first_name
       FROM posts p
            LEFT JOIN users up
                      ON up.id = p.user_id
            LEFT JOIN reposts rp
                      ON rp.post_id = p.id
            LEFT JOIN users urp
                      ON urp.id = rp.user_id;
```